# Use of the joker from your hand

Tags: rummikub

You have a joker in your hand, can you play it by adding to an existing run or set? Or do you have to play it with at least 2 additional tiles from your hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to an existing run or set, the only time you have to play 2 tiles with it is if you are replacing it from the board.